# How to estimate the width/height size of output image in a target CRS without gdalwarp?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, gdal, java, gdalwarp

I have a hard problem to find the width/height of a 2D GeoTiff file 
which is reprojected from a source CRS (e.g: EPSG:4326) to target CRS 
(e.g: EPSG:3857) without running gdalwarp. Because, the file could be 
large (GBs) and I don't need the projected output file, just need the 
width/height of it.

What could be done with gdalwarp is:

```
gdalwarp  -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 full.tif full_3857.tif 

gdalinfo full_3857.tif 

Size is 879, 811 (width/height).
```

I've searched a lot and what seems to be good without doing the real 
projection is this gdal function: **GDALSuggestedWarpOutput2** 
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/106c8288e7a05f4efc1a588c5a3b2da7ec52d915/gdal/alg/gdaltransformer.cpp#L354. 
However, it doesn't help because my application developed in Java and it 
uses gdal-java (GDAL JNI) https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.gdal%7Cgdal%7C1.11.1%7Cpom
as library.

Unfortunately, I cannot find this GDALSuggestedWarpOutput2() 
from gdal-java http://gdal.org/java/overview-summary.html then cannot 
invoke this C++ function from my application to test.

Can anyone please give me a hint to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above mentioned solution is in python. Since you are using java, following is the solution in java language.

```
    gdal.AllRegister();

    Dataset source_file = gdal.Open("mean_summer_airtemp.tif");

    String source_srs = source_file.GetProjectionRef();
    SpatialReference sSRS = new SpatialReference(source_srs);

    SpatialReference dSRS = new SpatialReference();
    //sSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326); // Need not import, let it be the original source SRS
    dSRS.ImportFromEPSG(3857);

    String source_wkt = sSRS.ExportToWkt();
    String dest_wkt = dSRS.ExportToWkt();

    double error_threshold = 0.125;
    Dataset reproj_file = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(source_file, source_wkt, dest_wkt, gdalconstConstants.GRA_NearestNeighbour, error_threshold); 

    System.out.println("Source raster Dimension: "+source_file.GetRasterXSize()+" "+source_file.GetRasterYSize());    
    System.out.println("Reproj raster Dimension: "+reproj_file.GetRasterXSize()+" "+reproj_file.GetRasterYSize());
```

It will help finding the dimensions of raster without using gdalwrap.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, one can use GDAL function: [AutoCreateWarpedVRT](http://gdal.org/java/org/gdal/gdal/gdal.html#AutoCreateWarpedVRT-org.gdal.gdal.Dataset-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-double-)

An example of how it works in Python to get the ul_x, ul_y, lr_x, lr_y and pixel_size_x, pixel_size_y

```
from osgeo import gdal,osr

source_file = gdal.Open("mean_summer_airtemp.tif")

source_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
dest_srs = osr.SpatialReference()

source_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
dest_srs.ImportFromEPSG(3857)

source_wkt = source_srs.ExportToWkt()
dest_wkt = dest_srs.ExportToWkt()

error_threshold = 0.125
reproj_file = gdal.AutoCreateWarpedVRT(source_file, source_wkt, dest_wkt, gdal.GRA_NearestNeighbour, error_threshold)
reproj_attributes = reproj_file.GetGeoTransform()

print reproj_attributes
```